# Android - Creating an entry in db then starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a simple application that `onClick` creates a new entry in a sqlite db and then creates a new intent and starts a new activity. What are the chances of this "messing" up? Will java wait for it to be done with the db entry before moving on?

```
DBAdapter test_db = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
test_db.createEntry(level, phase, a, b, c, d);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there anyway that starting the new activity could mess up the new db entry if it moves through it too fast for some reason?

Comment: you can add a check(maybe if condition) to compare the previous row count and new row count after adding the entry.
if new count-1==old count you call your intent

Comment: What is the problem? Is new activity not started at all or it takes time? The entry should be done pretty fast. Show some code.

Comment: `Is there anyway that starting the new activity could mess up the new db entry if it moves through it too fast for some reason?`

Comment: Starting of the new activity could be messed up(more precisely is not going to happen) if your database insertion will throw an exception. Otherwise your code will run your insert code and after this happens it will start the new activity. Of course database operation should be done out of the main UI thread otherwise if the database access lags you'll find your app also lagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get the exact answer I wanted. But, turning strict mode on in developer settings in android didn't make it go off. So I'm just keeping this code.